# How to use g++-3.4 in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I want to use g++3.4 in ubuntu 15.04, but I have trouble doing it for a week.

I followed the answer to install g++3.4.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/39628/old-version-of-gcc-for-new-ubuntu

And I chose g++-3.4 with the method provided on

https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version

When I want to compile a cpp file, an error display:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s.
```

So I searched a lot of information about the problem, I find the following:

http://serverfault.com/questions/266138/cannot-find-lgcc-s-from-gcc-3-4-on-ubuntu-11-04

Because I don't have i486-linux-gnu directory, I typed

```
sudo ln /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1  /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so
```

But the terminal displayed the error:

```
ln: failed to create hard link ‘/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so’: File exists
```

then I type the command

```
sudo cp /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

It seemed to work. But when I compiled again, the terminal showed that

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/3.4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

Afterward I thought that it was because I didn't have 32-bit support. But I couldn't download ia32-libs package. It seems that the package don't exist on latest ubuntu.

Now I have installed gcc-multilib,lib32gcc1 and libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, and I also have tried the command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I still don't have 32bit support. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

---

Not sure you need a 32bits compiler ? Anyway, none of the older compilers, gcc versions 4.3 and lower can be used with Ubuntu 11.10 ... 15.10 .
The information in "askubuntu" etc. is wrong.

---

The usable version of gcc/g++-3.4.6 is { compat-gcc34-3.4.6-ubuntu1204-1_amd64.deb, compat-gcc-34-c++_3.4.6-20_amd64.deb }

Links for the "amd64 packages" :

compat-gcc34 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRTkzQnRSNXZ6UVU/view?usp=sharing

compat-g++34 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV3J3bnVoWGNWdG8/view?usp=sharing

.... provides /usr/bin/{ gcc34, g++34 }.

---

[compat-gcc34](/questions/tagged/compat-gcc34)